# JSON Write Error - Invalid type when dealing with custom classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I have a number of custom classes, subclassed from NSObject, that I'm trying to write to a JSON file. My top level class, called Survey, is a singleton, and one of its properties is addressArray, which contains instances of another class called Address.

There can be any number of addresses in Survey's addressArray, and I'm trying to write all the data to a JSON file. My code is as follows:

```
//In both Survey.m and Address.m, I have a method like this: 
- (NSDictionary *)surveyDictionaryRepresentation
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dictionary[@"name"] = [self name] ? : [NSNull null];
    dictionary[@"emailAddress"] = [self emailAddress] ? : [NSNull null];
    dictionary[@"addressArray"] = [self addressArray] ? : [NSNull null];
    dictionary[@"storage"] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self storage]] ? : [NSNull null];
    dictionary[@"extraStops"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self extraStops]] ? : [NSNull null];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];
}
```

Then, in the view controller, I have the following in the ViewDidLoad method.

```
NSArray *surveys = @[[[Survey sharedInstance] surveyDictionaryRepresentation]];
NSMutableArray *addresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (Address *address in [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]){
    //What the hell was I thinking? 
    [addresses addObject:[addressaddressDictionaryRepresentation]];
}
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"Survey": surveys, @"Address":addresses};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Now, I'm getting the following error: 
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Address)'

I can see why there would be a problem. Because addressArray, containing instances of Address, is in Survey, there seems to be a problem with adding the Address data to the JSON object created for Survey. I'm not sure how to get around this problem. After using breaking points to step through the program, I see that the crash is occurring after it attempts to execute the line: `NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];`

For what it's worth, I NSLog'd the addresses array after looping through it and running the addressesDictionaryRepresentation method on its contents, and it logged perfectly, showing all the properties and all the values perfectly. I just cant get it into the JSON document. Any suggestions? Help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: First few lines of the log of AddressArray:

```
  2015-02-18 11:21:29.122 [70958:920733] (
    {
    aCCOI = "-1";
    aCfloorNumber = "<null>";
    activity = 0;
    addressType = "-1";
    allowedToReserveDock = "-1";
```

EDIT 2: The only other code in Survey.m is that which establishes the singleton: 
    + (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static Survey *_instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[Survey alloc] init];
    });
    return _instance;
    }

EDIT3: 
    if ([self addressArray]){
        NSMutableArray *addresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (Address *address in [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]){
            [addresses addObject:[address addressDictionaryRepresentation]];
        }
        dictionary[@"addressArray"] = [self addressArray];
    } else {
        dictionary[@"addressArray"] = [NSNull null];
    }

Comment: NSJSONSerialization can only serialize NSDictionary, NSArray, NSNumber, NSString, and NSNull.  Any other objects must somehow be converted to those.  Typical is to define an `asDictionary` method for the class which returns it's reprentation as an NSDictionary (and a corresponding `initWithDictionary:` method to go the other way).  (Though understand that you must somehow arrange for these methods to actually be invoked -- it's not automatic.)

Comment: Side note: `for (Address *address in [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]){
    [addresses addObject:[[[[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]objectAtIndex:[[[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]indexOfObject:address]]addressDictionaryRepresentation]]; }` looks redundant, why don't you use the adress object directly? Like `for (Address *address in [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]){
    [addresses addObject:[address addressDictionaryRepresentation]]; }`

Comment: For the issue, I guess that addressDictionaryRepresentation somehow does not return a JSON serializable object but contains Adress objects somewhere. You should have a look at the output of that method.

Comment: E.g., what does [self prop1] return for the Address object?

Comment: @HotLicks: What you suggested is already in the code he provided (see addressDictionaryRepresentation)

Comment: @Kim - But apparently it doesn't work or is not being used properly. Likely because the OP copied code he does not understand.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yep, that's right. That method does not return a proper JSON dictionary representation.

Comment: The dictionaryRepresentation methods work, but they aren't called automatically. For example, converting the properties of Survey into an NSDictionary is all well and good, but one of those properties is an Array that contains instances of Address, which also needs to have its own dictionaryRepresentation run on it. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the dictionaryRepresentation method for Address run automatically as needed.

Comment: I really like the for-loop with objectAtIndex:indexOfObject :-)

Comment: Jay, show us the NSLog of your `addresses` array.  (Or the first dozen or so lines of it.)

Comment: So, like I said, I'm logging the output for the addressDictionaryRepresentation and surveyDictionaryRepresentation methods, and its coming out fine individually, but trying to package all of it into 1 big chunk of JSON is difficult because the dictionaryRepresentation methods don't get called automatically.

Comment: Your ..DictionaryRepresentation methods must call each other as needed to convert any objects contained therein.  It's really quite straight-forward and "cookbook" once  you get the basic idea down.

Comment: Inside the surveyDictionaryRepresentation, one of the [self propX] lines will probably return the addresses array. So that method could call addressDictionaryRepresentati‌​on before returning that.

Comment: Updated question with NSLog of addressArray.

Comment: Could you post the real implementation of the surveyDictionaryRepresentation method? What you have there seems to be a dummy (with that prop1, prop2 stuff).

Comment: Also the whole Survey class implementation would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know what the hell I was thinking in that for loop. I've been so frustrated with this problem. Chalk it up to a) me being new and b)frustration induced stupidity.  

Anyway, question updated with requested code.

Comment: Yeah, that can happen when you're frustrated. No big deal, just always review your code later when you're cool again :-) I posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[self addressArray] should return an JSON array, not one with Address objects. Just like you did for the @"Address" field:
`NSMutableArray *addresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (Address *address in [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray]){
    [addresses addObject:[addressaddressDictionaryRepresentation]];

}`
Return that NSMutableArray addresses so it gets set as value for @"addressArray". Then you should be fine.

Comment: As the addressArray method is used in other places, you should probably make new method. E.g. [self addressJSONArray] and return the addresses object from above.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot shortly and will green-checkmark you accordingly once I can get it to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Np, hope it helps. Just shout here if it still doesn't work. Maybe I also missed something.

Comment: It works. I am screaming profanities at my computer out of excitement. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do, in the ClassX `toDictionary` method, is create a mutable dictionary, then insert each instance value/property as is appropriate.  For a pointer to another class I call the `toDictionary` method of that class.  For a pointer to an array of ClassY objects, I create a mutable array, then call the `toDictionary` method of ClassY for each element of the array.

There's no real point in creating a separate `toArray` method to handle an array of ClassY, since the array handling is easy "boilerplate" to code directly in the calling method.